# TypeScript: ES2015 string property 'repeat' not recognized

Tags: typescript

Condition: I'm working on Win10, TypeScript 1.8, and Visual Studio Code 1.0.0. I have code like

```
///<reference path = "./typings/lib.es6.d.ts" />
```

and, later

```
let z = "0".repeat(4 - str.length)
```

This is the `let z` line.

VS Code put red underlines under "repeat" and reported

```
[ts] Property 'repeat' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I compiled at the command line with

```
tsc <filename>.ts
```

Pointing at the start of `repeat` in the `let z` line, the compiler reported

```
error TS2339: Property 'repeat' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Beggin' to differ, TypeScript, but that was added with ES2015 (ES6).

Question: How can I get a clean compile?

EDITS: Shortened.

Comment: A short-term, indirect solution is to use a library like lodash (especially if you already have it in your project). You could use the syntax `_.repeat('0', 4 - str.length)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, I only changed this line on `tsconfig.json` file:

Before:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
}
```

After:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
}
```

Comment: Elegant. Way better approach than mine.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was:

(1) Remove all references to d.ts files and compile. It seemed some of my problems came from overlapping definitions in various d.ts files. With all of those files gone, the compile told me what problems were "real". One of them was this one.

(2) In my project directory, I created a `typings` directory. I'll make a habit of putting almost all d.ts files there. Modules get a directory there. (For instance, I have a `typings\node` that holds `node.d.ts`.)

(3) In `typings`, I have a file I'm slowly building; some call it `globals.d.ts` and lots of people seem to prefer `index.d.ts`. In it, I put all the solutions I've needed. This was one of them; `string.substr` was a second. The relevant part of that file:

```
interface String {
    repeat(count: number): string
    substr(from: number, length?: number): string
}
```

And where'd I get that? Anywhere with something that works! I found these two lines in a copy of `lib.es6.d.ts`.

(4) Cite that file in your source code via `/// <reference path="./typings/index.d.ts" />` (subject to whatever you call the file). Compile. Repeat (3) as needed. When all the errors go away, my d.ts is complete enough. Someday, I'm bound to add more source code that'll need more here, but that's a later problem.

Is everything sweetness and light? Certainly not.

I'm past this error, but there's another that is particularly perplexing.

I've read some development tickets the TypeScript team shares with the public. They definitely understand the whole problem. It's not easy to fix. They're chipping away at it. When they're done, I think they hope this will no longer be a problem.

Sometimes, even with the amazing resource of `typings` on npm, the most recent version of a d.ts file I can find seems likely to be out of date. (The most recent version of node.d.ts is labeled for v4.x; I'm using v5.11 and v6.0 is out. Of course, v4.4 is the long-term-support version most suitable for production use. Sure. Still, I'm not fully confident I'll always be able to find a solution.)

If the lines in those files make my errors go away, they're good enough for me. Sometimes, they don't.

If I can figure out the typings on my own, that's best case. I'm developing toward full ability to do that. (So ... sometimes, I can't! Sigh.)

I'll be glad to understand everything related to these issues!

Answer (score 0):

In my special case (perhaps *very special!*) `"files"` entry in `tsconfig.json` had pointed to an incorrect file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "exclude": [
        ...
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/wrong.ts"  // <= CHECK THIS
    ]
}
```